# Count number of 0's on each column

Tags: r, count, tibble

My problem is quite simple but I not beeing able to solve him. I have a tibble dataframe and want to know how much 0's each column have. I tried to use the function sum(dataframe$column == 0) on each column but I think this is kinda inefficient since I want to apply this to a bunch of differents dataframes. Are there any other more automatic way to do it?

Comment: `library(tidyverse); mtcars %>% summarise_all(~sum(.==0, na.rm=TRUE))`

Comment: WIth `base R`, `colSums(df1 == 0)` or `colSums(!df1)`